# how to get best order to resolve dependencies

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a series of nodes that have  dependency relations.

```
(a:Foo)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(b:Foo)
```

Each node can depend on 0 or more other nodes and there are no loops.

I need a query to return all the node in the best order to process the nodes before processing the nodes that they are dependent on.

I know I should show what I tried, but I am a novice to graph theory and I can't figure out how to start writing the query.

UPDATE:
The processing I want to do is, say I have:

```
(a)-[:DEPENDS+ON]->(b)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(c)
(d)
(e)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(f)
(g)
```

I need to get the nodes out in an order so that nothing comes before any of its dependencies on the list. so:

```
d e g f a b c
```

would be one of several good orders. I don't  are about the exact order as long as the criteria is met.

Comment: Please provide details about the processing that you want to do.

Comment: If `a` depends on `b`, then doesn't `b` need to be processed *before* `a`, not afterwards?